# binomial distribution problem prove or disprove

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Let $Y_n\sim B(10, 2p) \wedge 0<p<\frac{1}{20}$.

prove or disprove:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p(|Y_n-20p|>\epsilon) = 0$

my try:

$p(|Y_n-20p|>ϵ)=p(Y_n-20p>ϵ)+ p(Y_n-20p≤-ϵ)
=p(Y_n>ϵ+20p)+p(Y_n≤20p-ϵ)=
1-p(Y_n≤ϵ+20p)+p(Y_n≤20p-ϵ)=$

But it goes complicated from here and I am not sure how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the question. Suppose $p=\frac1{40}$ and $\epsilon =1/4$.  Then    $\mathbb P(|Y_n-20p|>\epsilon) = \mathbb P(|Y_n-\frac12|>\frac14) = 1 \not \to 0$ since $Y_n$ only takes integer values

Comment: The parameters of your binomial distribution don't depend on $n$. I think you have copied the question wrongly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it's suppose to be not depended on n. because that it is disprove as Hentry said